# Only redirect unauthenticated users for missing resources, within Koa.js?

Tags: javascript, http, koa, passport.js

My application uses Koa.js, with [koa-passport](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport) for it's authentication logic. The way I set it up, is that the middleware (passport) is inserted between the public content (js, css, img, etc.), or more precisely the [static](https://github.com/koajs/static) middleware, and the private controllers (using [trie-router](https://github.com/koajs/trie-router)). Then, the request is simply redirected to a login url if an unauthenticated user tries to access the router.

Now, the problem I have is that, when some images are missing in the public asset folder, I get to the authentication middleware, and redirected to the login url, again. This is problematic as I get several `302` redirections in my logs and I would like to prevent this.

Is there anyway to safely know that the request would match a route within the trie-router as a precondition to redirect, otherwise return a `404` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your configuration code?

Routes are still matched on a path, so if you only mount your authenticate middleware on those paths then it should work as expected. EG:

```
app.use('/private', passport.authenticate());
```

Comment: So, you are suggesting, instead of mounting passport as a middleware directly on the application, I should compose it with every "private" routes?

Comment: Yes. From an information architecture standpoint, it's not uncommon for all private routes to be under just a couple root paths, or possibly path patterns.  Though if the "every" worries you, you can try and do some regex path matching for the mount point to save some configuration space.

Comment: I understand. I don't have *that* many routes, but I was avoiding repeating composing unnecessarily. But, in the end, laziness will always be the wrong approach :)

Comment: you don't have to repeat them that much, esp. if you have them along a path of some kind.  The matching algorithm is greedy, so if you have `app.use('/private', passport.authenticate())` and then later you can do something like, `var private = new Router(); private.get('/private/some-resource', handler);`, and it'll work.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't sure I could mix these... but I guess the router simply create a regexp (i.e. when using dynamic patterns) for the path, and Koa simply test if the string "starts with", is that it?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the static middleware yields if it cant find the file.

You could write a custom middleware, such as `fileNotFound()` below, that you use after the static and before the controllers.

Something like:

```
var serve = require('koa-static');

function fileNotFound(rootPath){
  var pattern = new RegExp('^' + rootPath + '/.*/')
  return function *(next){
    if(pattern.test(this.path)){
      this.throw(404);
    }
    else{
      yield next;
    }
  }
}
app.use(serve('/public'));
app.use(fileNotFound('/public'));

// add controllers after this
```

Comment: That won't work, as there is a router after the static middleware, and the routes may be dynamic, too (using the trie-router). The comments under [Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/53788/paul)'s answer is the correct way to do this.